# Should foreign Id properties be mapped from Model to Dto?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, graphdiff

If I have the following model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CustomerTypeId {get; set;}
    public virtual CustomerType {get; set;}
}
```

Should the Dto exclude foreign Id's to look like this:

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual CustomerType {get; set;}
}
```

And when using Graphdiff to update the object graph, will EF know that CustomerType maps to CustomerTypeId?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use it but you can avoid virtual member declaration. If you use `AutoMapper`, then the mapping will be done automatically. So, your Dto will look like this:

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CustomerTypeId {get; set;}
}
```

And the mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>();
```